# Asking someone if they can feel the blow of the fan in a room

Tags: meaning, expressions, sentence

In my EFL class, I wanted to ask one of the students who was farthest from the fan if they could feel the blow/wind of the fan, or if I had to place the fan somewhere else in the class.

[image: a picture to better understand the situation]

Imagine I wanted to ask the two students in the back if it was hot/cold, so that I knew whether to move the fan.
The following sentences came to my mind at that moment, but I was not sure:

- Do you feel/sense the blow/wind of the fan?
- Does its blow/wind hit you?

What's the most natural way to convey such a meaning? Is there an expression that serves this purpose?
Thanks

Comment: Is the fan effective enough for you guys?

Comment: A fan blows air, but a blow is a physical strike, as in a punch.

Comment: @deadrat -       Why blow doesn't mean puff of air?

Comment: blow as a noun can mean a punch, but blow as a verb means to "purposefully expel air".  A fan doesn't blow, but a hair dryer or a person can blow.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, what does a fan do if it doesn't blow? Just curious as I don't know what term to use here.

Comment: @Josh61 The *OED* lists the noun as the action of the wind with the verb *get*, but marks it as a mod[ern] colloq[uialism], for the value of *modern* equal to 1887. Even if we accept this meaning for a blow from a fan, it's probably best to avoid the expression as conjuring up the image of throwing the appliance at the students.

Comment: @alwayslearning actually a fan is said to blow, I beg your pardon.  You wouldn't say "the blow of the fan" as "blow" sounds like the noun form here rather than the verb.

Comment: "Do you feel the *breeze* from the fan?" is idiomatic. If you want to ask if the fan bothers them, "is the fan bothering you?" works well.

Answer (score 2):

Informally we would ask, "Can you feel the fan back there?"

Answer (score 1):

Asking people if they can feel the wind from the fan is liable to cause confusion.  What if they just say "Yes"?  What you really want to know is if you need to **adjust the fan**, so your question should address that.  I would say something like

> "Is anyone still too hot, or getting bothered by the fan?  I can move it if you like."

This more directly addresses the issue.